# Progressive matrix with clubs in 3x3 grids

Tags: visual, pattern, progressive-matrix

What is the solution to this puzzle? The question was vague, but I think it asked to find the next pattern.

[image: Puzzle]

Comment: Can you tell us what the question asks for?

Comment: I can't clearly remember, but it was something related to find the next pattern, and the question was really vague. I couldn't understand it.

Comment: Probably a little too vague....

Comment: :( yeah i guess

Comment: Hello there, where did you got this from?

Answer (score 14):

Feels like a

> C

to me

> Clubs are a constant in the puzzle, hence I do not see why it will change.
>  Across each horizontal line, the pattern move in a 45 degree clockwise movement.
>  
>  Hence C.

Comment: Clockwise along the rows, but also anti-clockwise along the columns.